# How to change default action on the second monitor in XUbuntu

Tags: xubuntu, multiple-monitors, 17.10

I was using LTS for a long time, and when a new monitor was getting connected a dialog would pop up asking me what to do. Now i'm on 17.10, the dialog also comes up when i connect the monitor, but by that time the system already chooses "mirror displays" for me.

I want to either change it to "use first display" or "extend to the right". How can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

There's a small bug on XFCE concerning this subject. Go to **Settings->Displays** and click on *Mirror Displays* to activate it and click on it again to deactivate it. Now your secondary display should be placed as an extension of the primary one and you should see two monitors on the left. Drag and place them wherever you like and apply the changes afterwards.

Comment: Nope. Didn't work. I did what you have suggested. Then unplugged the  second monitor and lugged it back in. When i did that, it once again displayed the dialog, and Mirror displays was selected.

Comment: This is indeed a bug in the dialog that pops up if you choose "Advanced" in the first dialog that pops up after connecting the external monitor. In this dialog, the external monitor is not visible at first. Following the steps in this answers makes it visible again. However, as the v010dya notes, this is not the answer to the actual question: how can we avoid that the first dialog pops in the first case, and that a default action is always choosen?

Comment: "how can we avoid that the first dialog pops in the first case, and that a default action is always choosen?" And once again you are not even reading my question, nor my comment explaining that you didn't answer it. This is getting upsetting now.